# Sum of exponential r.v.s - intuition

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition, exponential-distribution, moment-generating-functions

A student makes repeated attempts to solve a problem. Suppose the ith attempt takes
time $X_i$
, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. Each attempt
is successful with probability $p$ (independently for each attempt, and independently of the
durations). Use moment generating functions to show that the distribution of the total
time before the problem is solved has an exponential distribution, and find its parameter.

I found that the parameter is $p\lambda$. Does anyone have any intuition for why this should be? (if it is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Moment generating functions aren't needed here. First, we need to find the distribution of the sum of $n$ i.i.d. $\mathrm{Expo}(\lambda)$ random variables. Set $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. For $n=1$ we have for $t>0$:
$$
f_{S_1}(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^0}{0!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}.
$$
Now, assuming that $f_{S_n}(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ for some positive integer $n$, we find by convolution that
\begin{align}
f_{S_{n+1}}(t) &= f_{S_n}\star f_{X_1}(t)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} f_{S_n}(s)f_{X_1}(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t \frac{(\lambda s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda s} \lambda e^{-\lambda (t-s)}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t  \frac{(\lambda s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
&= \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda  t)^n}{\lambda  \cdot n!}\\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
(This is known as the Erlang distribution.)

Let $\{B_i:i=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. $\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ random variables, independent of the $X_n$. Set
$$
\tau = \inf\{i>0: B_i=1\},
$$
then $\tau$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb P(\tau = n) = (1-p)^{n-1}p,\ n=1,2,\ldots
$$
Let $Y = X_\tau$, then by conditioning on $n$ we may compute the density of $Y$ for $t>0$:
\begin{align}
f_Y(t) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{X_1\mid\tau=n}(t)\mathbb P(\tau = n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}(1-p)^{n-1}p\\
&= \lambda p e^{-\lambda t}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t(1-p))^n}{n!}\\
&= \lambda p e^{-\lambda t} e^{\lambda t(1-p)}\\
&= \lambda p e^{-\lambda pt},
\end{align}
and hence $Y$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda p$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clear and detailed solution. Do you have any intuition for why the result should hold?

Comment: @sph0 My blog post might give some insight: https://justanothermathblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/24/geometric-sum-of-exponential-random-variables/